# Create raster stack for every single band raster in the directory

Tags: r, for-loop, raster, r-raster

I'm creating a multi band raster from single band geo-tiffs. The idea is to create a stack from single band to multi (3) band, by stacking the single image three times. I can easily do this on single images by - `image1<-raster("image1.tif")`
`stack_image1<- stack(image1,image1,image1)`

How can I run this code snippet to run on all the raster images in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
Example files

```
f  <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
ff <- c(f,f,f)

library(raster)
x <- lapply(ff, function(i) stack(rep(i,3)))
```

Or with `terra`

```
library(terra)
x <- lapply(ff, function(i) rast(rep(i,3)))
```

or like this

```
y <- lapply(ff, function(i) rep(rast(i), 3))
```

Comment: Thanks Robert for the suggestion but I want to run `image1<-raster("image1.tif")` `stack_image1<- stack(image1,image1,image1)` image by image, meaning run the same code on image 2, image 3, image 4................. image 368, `image2<-raster("image2.tif")` `stack_image2<- stack(image2,image2,image2)` `image3<-raster("image3.tif")` `stack_image3<- stack(image3,image3,image3)`

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. Show some input code and show what you expect to get